# Ways of forming a committee so that a particular man is always included

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can a committee of 4 be selected from nine men so as to always include a particular man?
I thought 9 nCr3. as we only calculate to choose for 3 men out of the nine total. How am I wrong? Don't we have the consider the total ways that the other 3 people can be combined with that particular person.

Comment: I think it would be more like 3 out of 8, as one is already fixed.

Comment: in short, my concern is that this problem involves the fundamental counting principle. the probability of the 3 people are multiplied with that one person.

Comment: i.e. how many ways can those 3 people be paired with that one particular person. would this need to be counted?

Comment: The probability? Take a step back I'd recommend. The only question to answer is how many ways can you choose three additional people. Ordering is not important here.

Comment: So Mr. X is fixed; pick one of the others: 8 possibilities; pick one of the remaining 7: 7 possibilities; pick one of the remaining 6: 6 possibilities. Which gives you $8\times 7\times 6$ possibilities over all ;) Sorry for spoiling :( You still need to get rid of the ordering here though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the other 3 men from 8, not 9, possibilities.

So the answer is $\binom{8}{3} = 56$ not 84.